# Calculating Weekly Average in Excel 2019 using (DAX, Powerpivot, Powerquery)

Tags: excel, dax, powerquery, powerpivot

I have data in my table

[image]

I want to calculate weekly average. Like this
[image]

I can acomplish this by excel formulas but I am not fan of formulas. I need DAX, powerquery or powerpivot solution to automate the task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attached workbook uses power query to get to your desired output.

**Steps**

1. Replicate the date column
2. Transform the replicated date column to start of week
3. Group Rows by StartofWeek; create three additional columns
   [image: GroupBy Screenshot]
4. Close & Load as query conneciton only
5. Create a second Table query by repeating steps 1,2
6. Merge queries, joining on StartOfWeek column
   [image: MergeQueries]
7. Expand the WeeklyAvg columns and show the averages that you desire

This could also be done differently via DAX. Please let me know if this answers your request or if you have additional comments/suggestions. Thanks!

https://1drv.ms/x/s!AmcGUE_vrclQ7yIG6ZGnErO4m2LT?e=flnqio

Comment: Thank you! It worked. Never thought grouping will solve my problem.